# ICriteriaQuery not supporting AddUsedTypedValues with higher version of NHibernate

Tags: nhibernate, nhibernate-criteria

In older version of NHibernate there was a method called "AddUsedTypedValues" in ICriteriaQuery. After upgrading to NHibernate 3.1, such a method does not exist. Does anyone know where was that method moved (to another interface) or NHibernate removed support for it explicitly?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Method *AddUsedTypedValues* was replaced as well as the *(AbstractCriterion : )ICriterion* internal implementation. AddUsedTypedValues was a way how to inject parameters and they were later called inside ICriterion implementer like *sqlStringBuilder.AddParameter()*; (so the distance from Adding and usage was significant and not explicit)
Current versions (3+) provides ICriteriaQuery method

**IEnumerable NewQueryParameter(TypedValue parameter);**

which can be used to get an array of Parameters and then explicitly used when SQL statement is built:

```
var parameter = criteriaQuery.NewQueryParameter(typedValue).Last()
sqlStringBuilder.Add(parameter);
```

And now it is clear which parameter is added to a SQL statement. I had to implement my own ICrietrion, so I faced that issue as well...

Comment: There is no the NewQueryParameter() in the ICriteriaQuery for now :(